# ASP.NET not calling registered MessageHandler

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a working demo of a simple MessageHandler, as described in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and created a brand new project under "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)". In the template selection, my choice was "Web API". The project works fine (F5 shows the home page).

I change the `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` to look as the following:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.MessageHandlers.Add( new MyHandler() );               
        }
    }

    class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("MyHandler is running");
                var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                Trace.WriteLine("MyHandler is returning");
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("MyHandler caught exception: " + ex);

                Trace.WriteLine("MyHandler is rethrowing...");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the application with F5, I can step through `MessageHandlers.Add` and I see my handler being added. I can also step through the main controller.

However, my `MessageHandler` class `MyHandler` is never called.

What is missing?

Comment: Is this the possible issue illustrated here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997140/delegatinghandler-not-executing-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, that was the issue. Very hidden requirement, by the way.